# Editing text using innerText in for loop freezes the browser

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to use an element on page as a progress indicator (in percents).
However, when I call `innerText` inside of `for` loop, Chrome freezes and does not show the progress. Here is the sample code (just to showcase the issue):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="a">Hello!</h1>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initTrs(){
        for(var i = 1; i<=100; i++){
            document.getElementById("a").innerText = i;
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://www.google.com",
                async: false,
                done: function (a) {}
            });
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", () => initTrs());
</script>
</html>
```

Firefox works with it OK; however, Chrome freezes until `for` loop is fully done.

Could anyone help me out with this? Thanks!

Comment: You've specified the AJAX call to be syncrhonous, Chrome is treating it as blocking in the event loop, and thus waits for the loop to complete before updating the `innerText`. Why are you making the syncrhonous call?

Comment: I really wonder why this would work in FF. Because while JS is running, rendering of DOM typically is blocked. And by forcing your `ajax` call to act synchronously you are not letting the browser do any rendering ...

Comment: @BenM it is required for my API to work properly. Is there a way to optimize it w/o making a lot of requests at the same time?

Comment: @RodionGrinberg Why does your API care if calls are made to it either synchronously or asynchronously?

Comment: make the ajax call async and await it and also make initTrs async to be able to use await within it.

Comment: Well, you should read some tutorials about asynchronous programming. Your API for sure doesn't care whether your request is synchronous or asynchronous, but it *may* care about the number if parallel requests or the ordering of requests. But you can do that with asynchronous requests (and therefore without freezing the browser) also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it at the end:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="a">Hello!</h1>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initTrs(){
        for(var i = 1; i<=100; i++){
            const iter = i;
            setTimeout(() => {
                document.getElementById("a").innerText = iter;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://www.google.com",
                    async: false,
                    done: function (a) {}
                });
            });
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", () => initTrs());
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: as you didn't set a timespan in the `setTimeout`, it will have a timeout of 0 and you have 100 parallel (asynchronous) requests. If that's ok with your api, you don't need the `setTimeout` at all ...